# Create a function from struct

Tags: c, struct

Is it possible to create a function from struct?

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct dma
{
    int day, mes, year;
};

dma *x(int a, int b, int c)
{
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
}
```

and, this function return an struct..

If possible, how can I use them?

Comment: are you looking for a function 'belongs' to the struct [a method in OOP concept] or a function that returns a struct? please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you want to accomplish, but perhaps this is close enough?

```
struct dma
{
    int day, mes, year;
};

struct dma *x(int a, int b, int c)
{
    struct dma *res = (struct dma *)malloc(sizeof(struct dma));
    res->day = a;
    res->mes = b;
    res->year = c;
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct dma *m = x(1, 2, 3);

    printf("Year: %d\n", m->year);

    free(m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'dma *' :(

Comment: Oops. Edited source. 
Please also note the complete lack of error checking/handling, which should be added before actual use. :)